# Multiply column in dataframe with one row in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having problems with multiplying values in two different dataframes. Im doing a PCA regression and want to multiply all my loadings with the original values.

for example:

PCA dataframe

|  | PC1 | PC2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 0 | 1 |
| X1 | 1 | 2 |
| X2 | 2 | 1 |
| X3 | 2 | 1 |
| X4 | 3 | 2 |
| X5 | 5 | 4 |

Original dataframe:

|  | A | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 9 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

I then want to multiply PC1 with every row in the original dataframe such that:

PC1 = 0xA + 1xA1 + 2xA2 + 2xA3 + 3xA4 + 5xA5

insert first row from second dataframe:
PC1 = 0x1 + 3x1 + 4x2 + 2x1 + 3x2 + 5x8 = 59
Second row:
PC1 = 0x8 + 5x1 +3x2 + 2x2 + 1x3 + 5x2 = 28
Third row:
PC1 = 0x9 + 1x3 + 2x5 + 2x1 + 3x3 + 1x5 = 29

new dataframe:

|  | PC1 | PC2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 59 |  |
| 2 | 28 |  |
| 3 | 29 |  |

And so on.

My PCA dataframe have the shape (14,4) and my value dataframe has the shape (159,14)

Answer (score 2):

If same length of first `DataFrame` and same length of columns names in second DataFrame is possible multiple by numpy array with [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with rename columns names by `df1.columns`:

```
df = df2.dot(df1.to_numpy()).rename(columns=dict(enumerate(df1.columns)))
print (df)
   PC1  PC2
1   39   32
2   28   33
3   29   31
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a dot product - which you can get with `np.dot`

```py
print(df)
    2  3
1       
X   0  1
X1  1  2
X2  2  1
X3  2  1
X4  3  2
X5  5  4
```

```py
print(xf)
   2  3  4  5  6  7
1                  
1  1  3  4  1  2  4
2  8  5  3  2  1  2
3  9  3  5  1  3  1
```

```py
print(pd.DataFrame(np.dot(xf, df), columns=['PC1', 'PC2']))
   PC1  PC2
0   39   32
1   28   33
2   29   31
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
string = """    PC1 PC2
X   0   1
X1  1   2
X2  2   1
X3  2   1
X4  3   2
X5  5   4"""
string2 = """A  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
1   3   4   1   2   4
8   5   3   2   1   2
9   3   5   1   3   1"""
data1 = [x.split('  ') for x in string.split('\n')]
data2 = [x.split('  ') for x in string2.split('\n')]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x[1:] for x in data1[1:]], dtype = float), columns = np.array(data1)[0,1:])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data2[1:], dtype = float), columns = data2[0])





#Solution
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.dot(df2,df1), columns = ['PC1', 'PC2'])
```

Output:

[image]